# FUSE network file system and samba

Tags: java, web-services, rest, fuse

I'm trying to develop something, for learning purposes, that allows me to mount any kind of network resource (so an HTTP/FTP directory and stuff like that) as a local folder.

I'm using FUSE + JAVA with this library: https://github.com/EtiennePerot/fuse-jna

I chose JAVA because I need to make this work as a Web Service and I only know how to do this with JAVA.

Now, after this short intro, here's my scenario:

```
 _______________                ____________             __________
|               |              |            |           |          |
|remote resource|<--HTTP/FTP-->|fuse machine|<--SAMBA-->|desktop pc|
|_______________|              |____________|           |__________|
```

I've started with this example:

```
package net.fusejna.examples;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import net.fusejna.DirectoryFiller;
import net.fusejna.ErrorCodes;
import net.fusejna.StructFuseFileInfo.FileInfoWrapper;
import net.fusejna.StructStat.StatWrapper;
import net.fusejna.types.TypeMode.ModeWrapper;
import net.fusejna.types.TypeMode.NodeType;
import net.fusejna.util.FuseFilesystemAdapterAssumeImplemented;

public final class MemoryFS extends FuseFilesystemAdapterAssumeImplemented
{
    private final class MemoryDirectory extends MemoryPath
    {
        private final List<MemoryPath> contents = new ArrayList<MemoryPath>();

        private MemoryDirectory(final String name, final MemoryDirectory parent)
        {
            super(name, parent);
        }

        public void add(final MemoryPath p)
        {
            contents.add(p);
            p.parent = this;
        }

        @Override
        protected MemoryPath find(String path)
        {
            if (super.find(path) != null) {
                return super.find(path);
            }
            while (path.startsWith("/")) {
                path = path.substring(1);
            }
            if (!path.contains("/")) {
                for (final MemoryPath p : contents) {
                    if (p.name.equals(path)) {
                        return p;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            final String nextName = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("/"));
            final String rest = path.substring(path.indexOf("/"));
            for (final MemoryPath p : contents) {
                if (p.name.equals(nextName)) {
                    return p.find(rest);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void getattr(final StatWrapper stat)
        {
            stat.setMode(NodeType.DIRECTORY);
        }

        private void mkdir(final String lastComponent)
        {
            contents.add(new MemoryDirectory(lastComponent, this));
        }

        public void mkfile(final String lastComponent)
        {
            contents.add(new MemoryFile(lastComponent, this));
        }

        public void read(final DirectoryFiller filler)
        {
            for (final MemoryPath p : contents) {
                filler.add(p.name);
            }
        }
    }

    private final class MemoryFile extends MemoryPath
    {
        private ByteBuffer contents = ByteBuffer.allocate(0);

        private MemoryFile(final String name, final MemoryDirectory parent)
        {
            super(name, parent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void getattr(final StatWrapper stat)
        {
            stat.setMode(NodeType.FILE);
            stat.size(contents.capacity());
        }

        private int read(final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset)
        {
            final int bytesToRead = (int) Math.min(contents.capacity() - offset, size);
            final byte[] bytesRead = new byte[bytesToRead];
            contents.get(bytesRead, (int) offset, bytesToRead);
            buffer.put(bytesRead);
            contents.position(0); // Rewind
            return bytesToRead;
        }

        private void truncate(final long size)
        {
            if (size < contents.capacity()) {
                // Need to create a new, smaller buffer
                final ByteBuffer newContents = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) size);
                final byte[] bytesRead = new byte[(int) size];
                contents.get(bytesRead);
                newContents.put(bytesRead);
                contents = newContents;
            }
        }

        private int write(final ByteBuffer buffer, final long bufSize, final long writeOffset)
        {
            final int maxWriteIndex = (int) (writeOffset + bufSize);
            if (maxWriteIndex > contents.capacity()) {
                // Need to create a new, larger buffer
                final ByteBuffer newContents = ByteBuffer.allocate(maxWriteIndex);
                newContents.put(contents);
                contents = newContents;
            }
            final byte[] bytesToWrite = new byte[(int) bufSize];
            buffer.get(bytesToWrite, 0, (int) bufSize);
            contents.position((int) writeOffset);
            contents.put(bytesToWrite);
            contents.position(0); // Rewind
            return (int) bufSize;
        }
    }

    private abstract class MemoryPath
    {
        private final String name;
        private MemoryDirectory parent;

        private MemoryPath(final String name, final MemoryDirectory parent)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        private void delete()
        {
            if (parent != null) {
                parent.contents.remove(this);
                parent = null;
            }
        }

        protected MemoryPath find(String path)
        {
            while (path.startsWith("/")) {
                path = path.substring(1);
            }
            if (path.equals(name) || path.isEmpty()) {
                return this;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected abstract void getattr(StatWrapper stat);
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MemoryFS <mountpoint>");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            new MemoryFS().log(true).mount(args[0]);
        }
        catch (final Throwable e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    private final MemoryDirectory rootDirectory = new MemoryDirectory("", null);

    public MemoryFS()
    {
        // Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public int access(final String path, final int access)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int create(final String path, final ModeWrapper mode, final FileInfoWrapper info)
    {
        if (getPath(path) != null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.EEXIST;
        }
        final MemoryPath parent = getParentPath(path);
        if (parent instanceof MemoryDirectory) {
            ((MemoryDirectory) parent).mkfile(getLastComponent(path));
            return 0;
        }
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getattr(final String path, final StatWrapper stat)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p != null) {
            p.getattr(stat);
            return 0;
        }
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
    }

    private String getLastComponent(String path)
    {
        while (path.substring(path.length() - 1).equals("/")) {
            path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 1);
        }
        if (path.isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }
        return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    }

    private MemoryPath getParentPath(final String path)
    {
        return rootDirectory.find(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/")));
    }

    private MemoryPath getPath(final String path)
    {
        return rootDirectory.find(path);
    }

    @Override
    public int mkdir(final String path, final ModeWrapper mode)
    {
        if (getPath(path) != null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.EEXIST;
        }
        final MemoryPath parent = getParentPath(path);
        if (parent instanceof MemoryDirectory) {
            ((MemoryDirectory) parent).mkdir(getLastComponent(path));
            return 0;
        }
        return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int open(final String path, final FileInfoWrapper info)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final String path, final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset, final FileInfoWrapper info)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(p instanceof MemoryFile)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.EISDIR;
        }
        return ((MemoryFile) p).read(buffer, size, offset);
    }

    @Override
    public int readdir(final String path, final DirectoryFiller filler)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(p instanceof MemoryDirectory)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOTDIR;
        }
        ((MemoryDirectory) p).read(filler);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int rename(final String path, final String newName)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        final MemoryPath newParent = getParentPath(newName);
        if (newParent != null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(newParent instanceof MemoryDirectory)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOTDIR;
        }
        p.delete();
        ((MemoryDirectory) newParent).add(p);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int rmdir(final String path)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(p instanceof MemoryDirectory)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOTDIR;
        }
        p.delete();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int truncate(final String path, final long offset)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(p instanceof MemoryFile)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.EISDIR;
        }
        ((MemoryFile) p).truncate(offset);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int unlink(final String path)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        p.delete();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int write(final String path, final ByteBuffer buf, final long bufSize, final long writeOffset,
            final FileInfoWrapper wrapper)
    {
        final MemoryPath p = getPath(path);
        if (p == null) {
            return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT;
        }
        if (!(p instanceof MemoryFile)) {
            return -ErrorCodes.EISDIR;
        }
        return ((MemoryFile) p).write(buf, bufSize, writeOffset);
    }
}
```

but here comes a problem.

If I'm not wrong, FUSE loads the file content while listing a directory.

This means that the file has to be fully loaded even if the user is not opening it.

So the first question is: **how do I load the file "on demand" and without using the Proxy pattern?** (who loads an entire filesystem into the ram??)

While the first problem is between the remote resource and the fuse machine, the second one moves a step forward and involves the fuse machine and the desktop pc.

Since I'm talking about remote resources, this means that the fuse machine has to download them before sharing them with the desktop pc.
Of course this will cause 2 downloads of the same resource, one started by the fuse and the other started by the desktop pc.

Here's the second question: **is there any way to make my fuse machine return something like a link to the desktop pc when it opens a file?** (so that the desktop pc asks for a file, the fuse machine gives it a "link" and it starts to download it directly from the remote resource, avoiding one of the 2 downloads).

I know that the text is a little bit confused but I'm way more confused on this matter than the text itself so I apologize if I wasn't able to give a better explaination of what I need but I really don't know how to ask it!